# Unable to flash a stm32 (STEVAL-PTOOL1V1) : No device found on target

Tags: stm32

The board is a STEVAL-PTOOL1V1. The setup was tried on different boards.
The programmer board used is a STLINK-V3SET.

I followed the instructions on the `Getting started` document of the STEVAL-PTOOL1V1.

[image]

I power the board through J1 and J2 with a power supply supplying 12V.
I connected J8 with a jumper.
I connected the SWD pins to the STLINKS.

Here is the setup and the documentation for the SWD connector of the PTOOL1V1.
The pin at the bottom (with the red cable) is the first one. It has a square-shaped weld.

[image: setup]

[image: documentation swd]

In order to communicate with the board, I tried:

- Uploading the example project of the STEVAL-PTOOL1V1 by clicking on the debbuger icon of the CubeIDE
- Clicking "Connect" in STM32CubeProgrammer
- Clicking "Connect to the target" in STM32 ST-LINK Utility
- Using the Open source version of the STMicroelectronics STLINK Tools : stlink

Here are the errors messages for each:

```
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 5.9.1
Copyright (c) 2021, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
Persistent Mode : Disabled
Logging Level : 1
Listen Port Number : 61234
Status Refresh Delay : 15s
Verbose Mode : Disabled
SWD Debug : Enabled
InitWhile : Enabled

Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.
```

```
09:04:16 : STM32CubeProgrammer API v2.8.0
09:21:46 : Warning: Device changed, refreshing...
09:21:46 : ST-LINK SN : 002C00343156501620323443
09:21:46 : ST-LINK FW : V3J8M3B5S1
09:21:46 : Board : STLINK-V3SET
09:21:46 : Voltage : 3.21V
09:21:46 : No STM32 target found!
09:21:46 : ST-LINK SN : 002C00343156501620323443
09:21:46 : ST-LINK FW : V3J8M3B5S1
09:21:46 : Board : STLINK-V3SET
09:21:46 : Voltage : 3.23V
09:21:46 : Error: No STM32 target found!
```

```
09:22:17 : Can not connect to target!
If you're trying to connect to an STM32W1xx device, please select Normal or HotPlug mode from Target->Settings menu.
If you're trying to connect to a low frequency application , please select a lower SWD Frequency mode from Target->Settings menu.
09:22:23 : No target connected
```

```
$ st-flash --connect-under-reset reset
st-flash 1.7.0
2021-10-11T14:54:45 INFO usb.c: Unable to match requested speed 1800 kHz, using 1000 kHz
2021-10-11T14:54:45 WARN common.c: NRST is not connected
2021-10-11T14:54:45 ERROR common.c: Can not connect to target. Please use 'connect under reset' and try again
Failed to connect to target

$ st-flash --freq=50 --connect-under-reset reset
st-flash 1.7.0
2021-10-11T14:54:39 WARN common.c: NRST is not connected
2021-10-11T14:54:40 ERROR common.c: Soft reset failed: timeout
2021-10-11T14:54:40 ERROR common.c: Can not connect to target. Please use 'connect under reset' and try again
Failed to connect to target
```

In STM32CubeProgrammer, I tried changing the configuration of the STLINK. The port is at `SWD`. I tried `Hardware`, `Core` and `Software` for the reset mode. I tried `Normal`, `Under Reset` and `Hot plug` for the mode. Same result with every configurations.

When the board is powered, I have a tension of 3.3V on the VDD of the SWD connector.

Any idea why the flashing process is not working ?

Comment: Did you try a lower swd frequency?

Comment: I edited the post with a command at a lower frequency. It added an Error message to the output of st-flash. I tried all possible frequency provided by st-flash.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ST Link V2 to try it with? It works more stable.

Then use STM32CubeProgrammer with connect-under-reset at 5 Khz speed.

If that doesn't work either, your board is dead.

Comment: I tried to use the V2 with the configuration, but it did not work.
I ordered new boards and will update the post if the problem persists.